# Industry standards for threat names

Tags: network, ids

One of the security appliances we own reports a so-called "Industry Name" for the threats it detects on the network. I wanted to know if there is really such a standard and where I can find information about specific threats with a given industry name?

Comment: Please pass a couple of examples of the names.

Answer (score 1):

The security appliance report should say somewhere what standard it is using for the industry names. I am not sure how many standards are out there and it also depends on what kind of weaknesses your software is scanning for, but commonly I´ve seen reports using:

CVE (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) http://cve.mitre.org/

or

CWE (Common Weakness Enumeration) https://cwe.mitre.org/

Comment: CVSS also comes with the two. It represents a vendor-agnostic industry open-standard designed to convey vulnerability severity. You should add that to your answer.